# HTML/JS Nav Bar

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on a site at the moment and I have run into a problem which I am not sure if the problem is with my images or the html/JS code.

I am making a navigation menu with 7 images that will have a rollover effect and change to another image.

This is my code for the first image.

```
<div id="nav-menu">
 <a href="Culture.html" onmouseover="culture-nav.src='images/nav/over_culture.gif';"onmouseout="culture-nav.src='images/nav/norm_culture.gif';">
  <img border="0" src='images/nav/norm_culture.gif' alt="Culture-nav-button";name="culture_nav"/>
 </a>
</div>
```

When I created the images in PS, I used the slice too, and saved for web devices and png-24. However the two outer images are png, and the inner 5 are gif. Is this the problem, or is it my code, and how do I fix it?

ref: over_culture.gif(onmouseover) norm_culture.gif(hover/onmouseout)

Comment: You haven't actually described a problem? And I don't know what you mean by *outer* and *inner*, but there are not `png` images referenced in what you have in the question.

Answer (score 1):

this can be done only with css, as follows: (change the width and height according to your image size)

```
<style>
#nav-menu a{display:block;}
a.culture {width:100px;height:100px; background: url(/images/nav/norm_culture.gif) no-repeat 0 0 }
a.culture:hover{background: url(/images/nav/over_culture.gif) no-repeat 0 0}
</style>
<div id="nav-menu"> 
 <a href="Culture.html" class="culture">Culture</a> 
</div>
```